# In actionscript3, is it safe to stop my flash application when UncaughtErrorEvent occured?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, exception, error-handling

When a unexpected exception happened, 
I want to remove all DisplayObject and show error message to tell users that the program has crashed.

Is it safe to use UncaughtErrorEvent to do that?
Is it possible to stop my application even though it is not necessary to stop it if I use UncaughtErrorEvent to do that?

Comment: I'll add that only *you* ("The Programmer") knows when an exception is fatal or not.  UncaughtErrorEvent will catch all uncaught errors, regardless of whether the application "could" continue running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you can do this.

```
root.loaderInfo.uncaughtErrorEvents.addEventListener(UncaughtErrorEvent.UNCAUGHT_ERROR, onUncaughtError);

private function onUncaughtError(e:UncaughtErrorEvent):void
{
    // Do something with your error.
}
```

Note however that this is a feature of Flash player 10.1 and up I believe. This shouldn't be a big issue, since typically whenever a new flash player version is released people are forced to update.

Comment: thanks! do you use UncaughtErrorEvent in your application? doesn't it cause any problems?

Comment: Wow that's weird. Did you just accept this answer today? I didn't even get a notification on the 22nd when you asked if I've used this myself. Weird.... sorry for not getting back to you.

Comment: Yes, I accepted it yesterday. It's OK. Handling UncaughtErrorEvent worked fine. But I also had to handle UrlLoader.load()'s error events.